# The illustration for the code of conduct is broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, help-center, code-of-conduct

In the illustration accompanying [the code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), the part with the lady in the wheelchair is broken:

[image: excerpt from CoC illustration]

- The fill of her top is not aligned with the outline. Also it breaks the style of the image, being the only object with that sort of fill.
- The outlines of the wheelchair have overly pointy mitres and kinks. (On the other hand, the handles looking like jet engines is kind of cool).

Answer (score 4):

This is an *intentional* art style that appears in a great many places where we have custom-drawn images. See for example our [Engagement page](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/engagement) in the business section.

Comment: So all the mods diamonds are broken? Why isn't the blue offset? ;)

Comment: Is there a name for this technique? I have never seen this before (intentionally).

Comment: Okay, fair point. Still, protruding mitres do not seem to be your style.